# Table Splitting - Migration Warning

Tags: entity-framework-core

My scenario:

I have a **Product** that has various properties such a price, size, etc. that are declared in the Product Entity.

Additionally, a **Product** can have a collection of **StockRequirements**, i.e. when that Product is used the constituent **StockItems** can be depleted by the StockRequirement quantity accordingly.

Under one use case I just want the Product so that I can play with the core properties.  For another use case I want the Product with its StockRequirements.

This means that when retrieving a Product I may be using it in different contexts.  My chosen approach has been to use EF table splitting.

I have one repository for **Products** and one repository for **ProductStockRequirements**.  They are referring to the same unique Product.

The Product repository will provide a Product Entity with the core details only.

The ProductStockRequirements repository will provide ProductStockRequirements entity which does not have the core details, but does have the list of StockRequirements.

This seemed a reasonable approach so that I am not retrieving 'owned' StockRequirements when I only want to change the price of the product.  Similarly, if I'm only interested in playing with the StockRequirements then I don't retrieve the other core details.

**Entities**

```
class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CoreProperty { get; set; }
}

class ProductStockRequirements
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<StockRequirement> StockRequirements { get; set; }
}
```

**Product Mapping**

```
b.ToTable("Products");
b.HasKey(p => p.Id);
b.Property(p => p.CoreProperty).IsRequired();
```

**ProductStockRequirementsMapping**

```
b.ToTable("Products");
b.HasKey(p => p.Id);

b.OwnsMany<StockRequirement>(p => StockRequirements, b =>
{
    b.ToTable("StockRequirements");
    b.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("ProductId");
}

b.HasOne<Product>()
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<ProductStockRequirements>("Id");
```

When running a migration, I get the warning:

> The entity type 'ProductStockRequirements' is an optional dependent
> using table sharing without any required non shared property that
> could be used to identify whether the entity exists. If all nullable
> properties contain a null value in database then an object instance
> won't be created in the query. Add a required property to create
> instances with null values for other properties or mark the incoming
> navigation as required to always create an instance.

Focusing on the advice:

> mark the incoming navigation as required to always create an instance

I have tried:

```
b.HasOne<Product>()
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<ProductStockRequirements>("Id")
    .IsRequired();
```

and

```
b.HasOne<Product>()
    .WithOne()
    .IsRequired()
    .HasForeignKey<ProductStockRequirements>("Id");
```

to no avail.

The warning does not appear to result in any bad behaviour.  All my tests are passing.  But, it seems that I should be able to create a map that removed this warning, but cannot find the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should really just be

```
class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CoreProperty { get; set; }
    public List<StockRequirement> StockRequirements { get; set; } = new List<StockRequirement>();
}
```

As the StockRequiremens are not part of the Product entity, and [related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/) isn't loaded unless you request it.

And the Entity model is simply not the correct layer to define your aggregates.  An Aggregate is defined by selecting a single Entity from your entity model along with 0-few related entities.  Typically you include the closely-related and weak entities together in an aggregate.

If your entity model is a graph of 23 related entities, you might organize it into 10 separate and partially-overlapping aggregates or sub-graphs.

Comment: Thanks, David.  I could indeed use 2 methods on the Product Repository.  One to support the property update use case and one to support the stock management use case.  But, I still have the logic for the 2 use cases in the same aggregate.  I was motivated to use two separate aggregates focused on their respective use cases but using the same table for the aggregate entity.  It seems that table-splitting is the perfect answer to this challenge.  I can also make StockRequirements 'owned' on the second aggregate and not have to 'Include' them.  Am I complicating things unnecessarily?

Comment: Weak entities like StockRequirement don't get their own Aggregate.

Comment: Not sure I follow, or I've not been clear.  The two aggregates are `Product` and `ProductStockRequirements`.  The `ProductStockRequirements` then own a collection of `StockRequirement` that hold quantity and a pointer to the underlying stock item.  `StockRequirement` is never treated as an aggregate.

Comment: I understand.  I just don't agree that that's a useful design.

Comment: Thank you, more.  "And the Entity model is simply not the correct layer to define your aggregates."  Is your suggestion that I am trying to make my Entity Model implicitly support different use cases, instead of the use case aggregate explicitly deciding how to retrieve entities (and related entities) for the purpose of the use case?

Comment: Yes.  The Entity Model is not use-case specific.  It supports all your use cases, but none in particular.  An aggregate is kind of like a View Model in that way, as it's designed for a particular purpose.

Comment: The fog is clearing!  My assumption now is that `Product` is the root entity BUT ... I would create different repository methods to retrieve a Product with X or a Product with Y depending on why I want the Product.  The Product would then serve as the Aggregate for both use cases but would only have related entities loaded that are specific to the use case?

Comment: Yes.  And to keep things simple each Entity is always retrieved with all of its scalar-valued attributes, but only a subset of it's Entity-Valued attributes.

Comment: Thank you, kindly.  That all makes sense and I've just lost a few artefacts from my solution, reduced some complexity, whilst still delivering the desired outcome.

Comment: Refactored as above.  Tests all green.  Looks great.  One follow up ... Now all my logic related to Product (in all its guises for different use cases) is sitting in a single class.  Assuming a larger number of use cases with varying dependents, Product is going to become a bit of a monster.  What to do?  Suck it up?  I guess this is where I started and ended up exploring table-splitting!  Any recommended patterns to provide some segregation?

Comment: Actually, I think you answered that:  "If your entity model is a graph of 23 related entities, you might organize it into 10 separate and partially-overlapping aggregates or sub-graphs."